# How to send email on behalf of users in Google Apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, jakarta-mail, google-apps

I'm writing an app which needs to post emails on behalf of users of our Google Apps Premier domain. I see there is a way to do this using the AppEngine Mail Service if you have the admin credentials. I want to know how to do this from a normal Java app running on say Tomcat.

Comment: How is App Engine relevant here if you're not running on App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this, but if you have a Premier Apps domain then you should be able to enable and use oauth (you cannot with the free version) and follow these examples to send email on behalf of the users in your domain: http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/code.html if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine is a platform. You can't use App Engine services without writing an app that runs on App Engine.

Comment: I know. I was just using that as the example i.e. I want that similar functionality.

Comment: You say specifically that you want to do this "using the AppEngine Mail Service". Voting an answer down when it correctly answers the question you asked - as opposed to the question you meant to ask - is a bit unreasonable.

Comment: No, I did not. Please read the entire sentence. I was saying, I found that the AppEngine has such a feature which I would like on my normal Java app. I only used the AppEngine example because anyone familiar with the Google Apps platform might easily understand what I want.
And I don't think it's unfair to downvote such responses. At the end of the day, somebody looking to find an answer to this question would rather that this answer be at the bottom. Nothing personal.

Comment: Sending email from an app is a pretty standard thing to do in any language. Comparisons to App Engine specifically are pretty superfluous, and just add confusion.

Comment: Yes, but if you read my post, the question is about sending an email from an app ON BEHALF OF A USER OF GOOGLE APPS; the latter part needing attention which justifies the AppEngine comparision.